# Как сверстать изогнутую линию?

Tags: html, css, svg, canvas

Готовое решение не прошу :) как минимум на чем лучше это сделать canvas или svg(или более подходящий вариант)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А может быть блоку обертке сделать overflow: hidden и белые блоки сделать большой ширины с border-radius'ом?

Comment: Если зелёная фигура в макете сделана контурами, в новом фотошопе можно копировать из неё `svg`. Выдаёт вполне приличный чистый код, кстати.

Comment: я б если честно заюзал бы готовую png и прикрутил бы ее к родителю как `background-image`

Comment: @DenisRoss , мы тут не ищем лёгких путей!

Comment: @ГеннадийЖуров ну сама по себе реализация не через `background-image` довольно интересна) но на практике особенно при адаптивном дизайне с линией в виде отдельного элемента гемороя больше - следить чтоб не поехала и точно под картинкой и размеры учитывать при маштабировании.

Answer (score 6):

[это то что у вас на скрине в случае если в сниппете не корректно отобразится](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/ZMjPdj?editors=1100)

```css
.items {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 480px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: table;
  margin: auto;
  background: #fbfbfb;
}

ul {
  display: block;
  max-width: 360px;
  text-align: left;
  list-style: circle;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.ico {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  transform: scale(.6);
}

.ico div {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  border-right: 2px solid blue;
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
  transform: rotate(45deg)translateY(-1px)translatex(-2px);
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://enciklopediya-tehniki.ru/images/idoblog/upload/92/steril_24.png" width="360px" alt="">
  </div>
  <svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 314 69">


  <g
     transform="translate(-1.3,-227.2)">
    <path
       d="M 3.023821,295.48809 C 103.37996,270.41292 206.08908,254.16145 314.47619,259.20238 l -1.5119,-31.75 C 203.78198,275.16696 100.62384,269.86897 1.511911,228.96429 Z"
       style="fill:#00d6d6;" />
    </svg>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>Автоклавов - паровой стилизатор</li>
      <li>Используется для стирилизации инструментов</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="ico">
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <span> раскрыть подробнее</span>
</div>
```

Inkscape вот такую штуку сгенерировал - сама кривая

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 314 69">


  <g
     transform="translate(-1.3,-227.2)">
    <path
       d="M 3.023821,295.48809 C 103.37996,270.41292 206.08908,254.16145 314.47619,259.20238 l -1.5119,-31.75 C 203.78198,275.16696 100.62384,269.86897 1.511911,228.96429 Z"
       style="fill:#00d6d6;" />
  </
```

Answer (score 6):

Можно двумя радиальными градиентами

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.card{
  border:1px solid;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at center -200px, #fff 300px,transparent 301px),
              radial-gradient(circle at 75% 604px, #fff 500px,transparent 501px),
           #cda;
```

```html
<div class="card">
</div>
```

Comment: края рваные ..почему то

Comment: @НикитаФаст , особенность рендера градиента в браузерах

Comment: если чуть чуть цифры поменять наверно лучше будет ..

Comment: @НикитаФаст , сомневаюсь