# Как изменить в svg атрибут path при клике?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, svg

При клике на open сделать линию чуть шире (неважно на сколько, главное понять как это лучше сделать)

```html
<svg width=0 height=0>
  <defs>
  <symbol id="line">
  <g transform="translate(-1.3,-227.2)">
    <path
       d="M 0.023821,295.48809 C 103.37996,270.41292 366.08908,254.16145 314.47619,259.20238 l -1.5119,-31.75 C 203.78198,275.16696 100.62384,269.86897 1.511911,228.96429 Z" fill="#00d6d6" />
    </g>
  </symbol>
  </defs>
</svg>

<div class="column">
  <span class="open">
  Open
</span>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 304 69">
  <use xlink:href="#line"/></svg>
</div>
```

Comment: svg используете а [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/881179/308974) не принимаете?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самое простое - менять значение атрибута d у тега path:

```js
$('.open').click(function(){
   $('path').attr('d', 'M 0.023821,295.48809 C 503.37996,270.41292 1966.08908,254.16145 314.47619,259.20238 l -1.5119,-31.75 C 203.78198,275.16696 100.62384,269.86897 1.511911,228.96429 Z');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg width=0 height=0>
  <defs>
  <symbol id="line">
  <g transform="translate(-1.3,-227.2)">
    <path
       d="M 0.023821,295.48809 C 103.37996,270.41292 366.08908,254.16145 314.47619,259.20238 l -1.5119,-31.75 C 203.78198,275.16696 100.62384,269.86897 1.511911,228.96429 Z" fill="#00d6d6" />
    </g>
  </symbol>
  </defs>
</svg>

<div class="column">
  <span class="open">
  Open
</span>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 304 69">
  <use xlink:href="#line"/></svg>
</div>
```

Comment: А если несколько таких элементов? как через this до path добраться

Comment: @stiv, через this - никак, потому что this в данном случае будет указывать на $('.open'). Проще тогда каждому path задать какой-нибудь уникальный id и обращаться через этот атрибут.